# How to prevent of twice call one action in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use this code for display a view

```
namespace TravelEnterAdminTemplate.Controllers
{
   public class ArtPlacesController : Controller
    {
       private TravelEnterDBEntities1 db = new TravelEnterDBEntities1();
        private Models.Utility.ErrorLog errorlog = new Models.Utility.ErrorLog();


        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            try
            {
                var artPlaces = db.ArtPlaces.Include(a => a.AspNetUser).Include(a => a.City);
                return View(await artPlaces.ToListAsync());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errorlog.Error("IndexArtPlaces", "25", e.Source.ToString(), e.Message);
                return View("Error", TempData["Error"]);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I set break point  into index action and when debug app I found that this action twice call. I copy url and paste it in address bar and see that this action twice  call .
I try to detect that java script  statement done this work and put below code into head of page but does not alert for me before action call again.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

I run this code in console and when try to reload page get alert.
I think page do not reload but action call again.I think this problem is back end codes.

RouteConfig :

```
namespace TravelEnterAdminTemplate
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Check the client code, it may call your action method twice.

Comment: could you show the HTML & especially the Jquery which is making the call to the controller

Comment: I use url directly . and This do not happend when call actions with ajax

Comment: what happens if you rather use **public ActionResult Index()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my website layout  exits  `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" type="image/png">`  that `href="#"` Makes recall action. 
I delete this and solve problem.

Comment: that should be comment not answer